# Sending multiple variables to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have the following jQuery-enhanced Javascript within a HTML page:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){           
        $("#sb").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            getusername = "Yes";
            getpassword = "Yes";
            getusername = encodeURIComponent(getusername);//url encodes data
            getpassword = encodeURIComponent(getpassword);//url encodes data
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "get_login.php",
               data: {'username': getusername, 'password':getpassword},
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(data) {
                  $("#message_ajax").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.message +"</div>");
           }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My php is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Tester'));
}
```

The script isn't working however. I think it is to do with the way I am posting data from the browser. Perhaps I am incorrectly setting username and password and it is failing upon the isset statement?

Currently, the page does nothing. The button click event handler is triggering...but the message_ajax div in my HTML page isn't updating with correct response...

Comment: Are you sure that the markup contains an element with ID `message_ajax`? Try just `console.log(data)` in the `success` callback.

Comment: Do you use firebug? Check in the console, you can read the POST-strings and check if there are any errors

Comment: Maybe ypur browser chokes - because you do not initalize the variables with "var" ? And yes like above - what does firebug say?

Comment: shouldnt it be: `data: {username:getusername,password:getpassword}`, being keys not in single quotes

Comment: Don't URI-encode those items. jQuery will do it.

Comment: @Ronnie: Strictly speaking, yes. But that won't be a problem.

Comment: @user559142: You can narrow down this issue considerably by checking, with Firebug, the format of the outgoing HTTP request. Once you've verified that (and I think it'll be fine), you know that your issue is with your PHP. Suddenly your question has _half_ the scope and is far more manageable. You can then get to work finding what is probably just a syntax or logic error somewhere in the PHP script that you haven't shown us. Please get used to performing these sorts of debugging steps before asking here.

Comment: @Ronnie — keys in JavaScript object literals can be identifiers or strings. So either is fine. (JSON requires strings, and JSON strings always use double quotes, but that doesn't matter when you are writing JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
  $("#message_ajax").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.message +"</div>");
```

to

```
  $("#message_ajax").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.message +"</div>");
```

and try !!!

Comment: You forgot to add in a difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the mime header... your ajax is expecting json as a respons so you need to set the correct header.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests